# Removing a field from a comma delimited text with accented chars

Tags: perl, split, join

I have a CSV file that is like this

```
name;address;phone;email
John;123 La Sierra;555-121212;john@doe.com
Nick;456 La Bongaa;555-121232;nick@doe.com
Carl;789 La Fountain;553-121212;carl@doe.com
```

and I want to remove the last entry making it be like

```
name;address;phone;
John;123 La Sierra;555-121212;
Nick;456 La Bongaa;555-121232;
Carl;789 La Fountain;553-121212;
```

The last `;` has to be kept there but the last field removed.

I have found this code on a question of mine and adapted to this case

```
perl -000ne '@f=split(/;/); print join(";",@f[0..2]) , "\n"' myFile.csv
```

I thought it would split by `;` and then join just fields 0, 1 and 2 but it is not working.

`file` command gives me this result about `myFile.csv`

```
UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

The file contains accented characters that I think may interfere with this.

Any ideas?

Comment: @xhienne oops missed that requirement

Comment: @xhienne I've added a suggested perl implementation as a comment to your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I'm not sure you want a `perl` code so much, here is a similar `awk` code:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{ $NF=""; print }' data.csv
```

=> This code empties the last field of each line (`$NF=""`). Input fields (`-F\;`) and output fields (`OFS=';'`) are said to be separated with ";".

The same with `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^;]*$//' data.csv
```

=> This substitutes (`s/.../.../`) the longest sequence of characters that is not a ";" (`[^;]*`) at the end of the line (`$`) with nothing.

The same with `grep`:

```
grep -o '.*;' data.csv
```

=> `grep` regular expressions are greedy by default, that means that they match the longest sequence possible. Here `.*;` hence means "the longest sequence of characters that ends with a ";". The `-o` option outputs what is matched instead of the whole line.

Finally, a `perl` equivalent would be (thanks to @steeldriver):

```
perl -F';' -lpe '$F[-1]=""; $_ = join ";", @F' data.csv
```

=> It works similarly to `awk`, the joining being explicit here.

Comment: wow! What kind of sorcery is this? Are you a magician? BRILLIANT! Care to translate what each part of each command does?

Comment: @SpaceDog Done.

Comment: for the record, a perl equivalent can be written `perl -F';' -lpe '$F[-1]=""; $_ = join ";", @F' data.csv`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. I have added this to my answer. Feel free to amend/correct my poor attempt at an explanation of what it does. You may also add something about the paragraph mode you spotted in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

No cut? :(

If you're going to play with CSV files, [cut](https://ss64.com/bash/cut.html) is bound to become a friend :

`cut -f 1-3 -d';' semico.csv | xargs -I{} echo {}";"`

Breakdown :
Cut (extract) columns 1 to 3, delimited with ';'
Then for each line (as cut would remove the last ';', pass it to xargs and echo line + ;

Slower than the grep one for sure but in the long run probably best to use the right tool for the job

Alternative because people not happy with xargs :
`cut -f 1-3 -d';' semico.csv | sed 's/$/;/'`

Same thing but with sed where you tell to replace end of line with ;

Comment: what purpose does `xargs` serve here?  rhetorical question, the answer is "none" or "it makes this many times slower for no reason at all".     `cut -f 1-3 -d';'` would have made a good answer.  adding `xargs` ruined it.

Comment: @cas The OP requires that lines end with a ";". But using `xargs` to add an ending ";", that is executing `/bin/echo` for *each* line of the CSV, is certainly not using "the right tool for the job".

Comment: @xhienne okay, didn't notice that.  I can't think of any practical reason why the trailing `;` **needs** to remain - pretty much anything that uses or imports csv won't care.  and yeah, it was the "right tool for the job" line that inspired me to comment...also, I've seen way too many answers that use xargs for no good reason.  It can be a useful tool at times but that's no reason to use it where it isn't needed.

Comment: Hi folks, yes I'm aware xargs is not the right tool for the job but I figured showing an alternative wouldn't hurt. Added one 'right' way of doing that, but please feel free to show rather than tell

Comment: @ValentinPalussière - I have tested your answer, just out of curiosity, and it is not working for me with the following error `Illegal byte sequence`. I think it has to do with the fact that my file has accented chars... :(

Answer (score 1):

The `bash` way and using [`shell parameter expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) :

```
"${line%;*};"
```